# nodejs regex split limited occasions

Tags: node.js, regex

My string: `first part:second part:third part:fourth part: fifth part: etc`

My goal:

`array[0] = 'first part';
array[1] = 'second part';
array[3] = 'third part:fourth part: fifth part: etc'; // so including the : character if any`

I tried this regex but it doesn't seem to give the correct result:
`(.*?):(.*?):(.*)`

Any suggestions what I should be looking for?

Comment: What is wrong with your current matches? You match 3 groups which contains your values. [`(.*?):(.*?):(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/PbE486/1)

Comment: You can only expect it that way: `array[0]` is the whole match, `array[1]` - the first part, etc.

Comment: You were right the fourth bird, I was correct before I even started. Got a little confused I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your original regex [`(.*?):(.*?):(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/PbE486/1) which matches your values in 3 capturing groups.

Then use `slice(1)` [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to return all elements except the first item (which is the full match) from the array that match returns:

```js
let str = "first part:second part:third part:fourth part: fifth part: etc";
console.log(str.match(/(.*?):(.*?):(.*)/).slice(1));
```

Comment: I ended up using  `var result = line.match(/(.*?):(.*?):(.*)/);` which gave me result I was looking for. Looking back at this question I think I already had it right beforehand but got a little confused while setting up my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RegEx [`([^:]*):([^:]*):(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/fvZUEG/1)

- `([^:]*)` matches anything but a `:` 0 or more times
- `:` matches `:` literally
- `(.*)` matches anything 0 or more times

To get your expected result, you can use `Array#splice` on your regex results.

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/fvZUEG/1)

```js
let data = "first part:second part:third part:fourth part: fifth part: etc";
let regex = /([^:]*):([^:]*):(.*)/;

console.log(regex.exec(data).splice(1,3));
```